# INSERCIÓN EN BASE DE DATOS

Tags: php, mysql, validación

Cómo podría controlar el ingreso de productos al almacén de mi sistema por medio de seriales y que los mismos se guarden en una misma categoría. Por ejemplo

```
Producto 1

Categoría: impresoras y escaner
Producto a ingresar: impresora epson tw45 serial 457454545gg

Producto 2

Categoría: impresoras y escaner
Productor a ingresar: impresora epson tw45 serial 4574545458a
```

Quiero que estos dos productos se incluyan en el stock de la categoría con la misma marca y modelo pero con diferente seriales.

Así tengo mi base de datos...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `Categoria` (
  `IDcategoria` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `nombre_categoria` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDcategoria`)  COMMENT '',
  UNIQUE INDEX `nombre_categoria_UNIQUE` (`nombre_categoria` ASC)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `Articulo` (
  `IDarticulo` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `IDcategoria` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `nombre_articulo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `codigo_articulo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `stock_articulo` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDarticulo`)  COMMENT '',
  UNIQUE INDEX `nombre_articulo_UNIQUE` (`nombre_articulo` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  UNIQUE INDEX `codigo_articulo_UNIQUE` (`codigo_articulo` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  UNIQUE INDEX `stock_articulo_UNIQUE` (`stock_articulo` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_Articulo_Categoria_idx` (`IDcategoria` ASC)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas sobre cómo elaborar una buena pregunta y evitar que sea cerrada.

Comment: Es lo que te he respondido, necesitas tres tablas. Con dos, únicamente puedes almacenar modelos, pero no impresoras concretas con diferente serial, ¿ves que tienes IDarticulo y codigo_articulo en la misma tabla? Por otra parte, tampoco has definido claves ajenas. En cualquier caso, ¿qué quieres obtener? Edita la pregunta dejando un listado de lo que querrías mostrar. Si no lo defines, cerrarán la pregunta.

Comment: Mi clave foranea es Id_categoria en la tabla articulo @David

Comment: Pues no figura en el SQL

Answer (score 1):

Aunque podrías registrarlo en una única tabla, te recomendaría normalizar tu base de datos y registrar categorías, productos y números de serie en tablas diferentes. De esta forma sólo registrarías la categoría y el producto una única vez, y utilizarías la referencia del producto para registrar en tu almacén unidades concretas con su número de serie propio. Los productos son entidades abstractas y las unidades en stock elementos concretos y tangibles. Te adjunto el modelo ER, el código MySQL que genera la base de datos y el diagrama resultante. Espero que te resulte útil.

[image: Modelo ER]

```
CREATE TABLE categorias(
  categoria varchar(31),
  PRIMARY KEY(categoria)
  );
CREATE TABLE productos(
  producto varchar(31),
  categoria varchar(31),
  PRIMARY KEY(producto),
  FOREIGN KEY(categoria) REFERENCES categorias(categoria)
  );
CREATE TABLE stock(
  producto varchar(31),
  n_serie varchar(31),
  PRIMARY KEY(n_serie),
  FOREIGN KEY(producto) REFERENCES productos(producto)
  );
INSERT INTO categorias (categoria) VALUES ('impresoras y escaner');
INSERT INTO productos (producto, categoria) VALUES ('impresora epson tw45','impresoras y escaner');
INSERT INTO stock (producto, n_serie) VALUES ('impresora epson tw45','457454545gg');
INSERT INTO stock (producto, n_serie) VALUES ('impresora epson tw45','4574545458a');
SELECT * FROM productos JOIN stock USING(producto);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Algo parecido a eso tengo mi base de datos, solo que el stock lo tengo como un atributo en la tabla productos..

Comment: Por eso lo recomendable es que edites la pregunta (como te están pidiendo los moderadores) y aportes tu código en SQL (en phpMyAdmin, Exportar). Con respecto al stock, la clave es el S/N o P/N, en tu caso ese serial es más bien P/N, ya que es diferente para cada impresora física. En cambio, el S/N es común a todos los elementos fabricados, pero único para cada modelo.